# Where to find useful information to decide on installing "recommended" updates?

Tags: windows-update

Generally, I have no problem with **critical** and **important** Windows updates; the vast majority of the time (in my experience) they do much more good than harm. Plus for these, which tend to be security updates, the [Microsoft Security Bulletin Summary](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/current.aspx) provides some good information, and the **Internet Storm Center** provides detailed, clear, and independent recommendations on each (see for example their [Feb 2011](http://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?storyid=10375) bulletin).

Deciding on installing **recommended** updates, on the other hand, is fraught with much trepidation. Let me interject here that I have great respect for Microsoft developer tools: Visual Studio is amazing; I am enamored of LINQ; and Win7 is quite cool.

But...

Today, for example, I had three recommended updates to consider. One (KB2454826) sounded fairly innocuous: "... a reliability update...to enable a set of performance and functionality update for graphics, media foundation, and XPS components on windows 7....". A quick web search, however, turned up [Microsoft pulls another botched auto update patch, KB 2454826](http://www.askwoody.com/2011/microsoft-pulls-auto-update-patch-kb-2454826/) from a site I have visited before. Since I do not have a graphics-heavy machine, I decided promptly this one was one to skip.

I started off very wary of the next one (2467023) because all it says is "Install this update to resolve issues in Windows." [sarcasm] Gee, I thought, a magic pill! I then went to the KB page that added little detail: "This update addresses issues that occur when Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 unloads and loads system binaries." The KB web page has lots of information on it--many screenfuls--but that one sentence is the only thing that attempts to describe the update. Come on, Microsofties! This is simply non-information. Who does this affect? And how often? And what are the ramifications? It sounds like this problem should affect everybody and very frequently. Doesn't the system load binaries *all the time*?

So my question is this: Is there a source (either from Microsoft or from a reliable third party) equivalent to Microsoft's Security Bulletin Summary for recommended or other non-security updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am really quite surprised that there is not more interest in this question. (Not because I posed it, but because errant patches can waste a lot of time for a lot of folks.) In any case, I have come across one reasonable source since I posed the question: Susan Bradley's [Patch Watch](http://windowssecrets.com/category/patch-watch/) column on [Windows Secrets](http://windowssecrets.com/).